# Is it correct I18n::setLocale('en_FR') in cakephp 4?

Tags: php, internationalization, cakephp-4.x

I'm working with i18n in my website with Cakephp 4.

My routes use languages with 2 characters (fr, en, it, etc.)

```
// Route For example 
$builder
        ->connect(
            '/{lang}/{controller}/{action}/*', 
            []
        )
        ->setPatterns([
            'lang' => 'fr|en|it'
        ])
        ->setPersist(['lang']);
```

As the country is not defined, when I do :

```
echo __(
    'Bonjour {0}, votre solde au {1,date} est de {2,number,currency}',
    ['Olivier', \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime::now(), 1354.37]
);
```

The currency is `¤` instead of `€`.

So I've set language with country FR in my `AppController` :

```
if($this->request->getParam('lang'))
            I18n::setLocale($this->request->getParam('lang') . '_FR');
```

The aim is to have `€` whatever the language.
Thus, it generates `fr_FR`, `en_FR`, `it_FR`.

Is it correct to do that or is it ugly ?

If someone could enlighten me...

Answer (score 1):

`¤` (`U+00A4`) is the character used to denote an unspecified currency, this is the expected behavior when not supplying a region alongside the language.

Instead of using a specific region you could use the `currency` keyword to specify the currency independently:

```php
// eg en@currency=EUR
$locale = "{$this->request->getParam('lang')}@currency=EUR";
```

I'm not sure though if the translate behavior will work properly with it, you might have to set the locale on the table instance manually so that it doesn't contain any keywords.

See also

- **[ICU Documentation > Locales and Resources > The Locale Concept > Keywords](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/locale/#keywords)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > Tree](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html)**

Comment: Indeed, the Translate Behavior doesn't work neither your solution, nor mine.
I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "to set the locale on the table instance manually" ?

Comment: @Oliv What I mean is before doing any operations on the table that involve the translate behavior, explicitly set the current locale on the table, eg `$this->Articles->setLocale($localeWithoutKeywords)`. Unfortunately this would need to be done for all involved associated tables that use translations too. When not providing the locale manually like this, the behavior will read it via `I18n::getLocale()`, where it would then retrieve for example `en@currency=EUR` instead of only `en`. Having the behavior filter out keywords might be something that could be added to the core though I think.

Comment: I've just create an issue at github, thanks.